# Visual Studio 2013 Web Load Testing Mystery

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

In visual studio 2013 Web load testing has changed. It was working fine for a long time. But lately when I run a test, all of the Page Response Times are "nothing" and under Controller and Agents I'm getting a red X every time, and Processor Time shows Error. Can't figure out why or what's changed.

[Image](http://alansimpson.me/Images/loadTest.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, my bad. Just realized the .webtest was empty. It didn't record in IE 11 because the web test recorder help add-in wasnt enable in IE11.